# In ember how do I wait for the result of a get to complete?

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple admin page that does the following:

```
  beforeModel: function() {
    var permission = this.get('userService.currentUser.userPermission.isAdmin');
    if(!permission) {
      console.log("no permission");
      return this.transitionTo('index');
    }
  },
```

User and UserPermission are separate models. UserPermission is loaded async.

This works great if I navigate to /admin (the permission object is already cached), but if I go to /admin directly it does not, presumably because the userPermission object hasn't been loaded.

Is there a way to say "get the userPermission then evaluate"?

Comment: Does getting the userPermission return Promise ?

Answer (score 1):

If suppose `this.get('userService.currentUser')` returns Promise, then you could do this, since `beforeModel` will resolve async operation before calling model hook.

```
beforeModel: function() {
    return this.get('userService.currentUser').then((userPermission) => {
        if (!userPermission.isAdmin) {
            this.transitionTo('index');
        }
    });
}
```